# Scratch Card Game setting percentage chances

Tags: java, random, integer

I have an assignment where I have a bonus game where I have to display four prizes and if the same  number appears more than one, they user wins that amount.
Problem I'm having is user wins every time! Very long winded code below.
I have four prizes, with 5 chances of winning all with different percentages. 50%, 27%, 15%, 6% and 2%.

```
    int[] bonus;  
        bonus = new int[5];
        bonus[0] = 10;
        bonus[0] = 20;
        bonus[0] = 50;
        bonus[0] = 200;
        bonus[0] = 1000;
        int [] bonusSum = new int[4];       
        int bonusAmount1=0;
        int bonusAmount2=0;
        
        
        numCount=0;
        
        //Select 4 bonus numbers
        while (numCount<4) {
            Random ran = new Random();
            int bonusNumber = rand.nextInt(99)+1;
                if (bonusNumber<49) {
                    System.out.print("€10 ");
                    bonusSum[numCount]=10;
                    numCount++;
                }else if(bonusNumber<27) {
                    System.out.print("€20 ");
                    bonusSum[numCount]=20;
                    numCount++;
                }else if (bonusNumber<15) {
                    System.out.print("€50 ");
                    bonusSum[numCount]=50;
                    numCount++;
                }else if (bonusNumber<06) {
                    System.out.print("€200 ");
                    bonusSum[numCount]=200;
                    numCount++;
                }else if (bonusNumber<02) {
                    System.out.print("€1,000 ");
                    bonusSum[numCount]=1000;
                    numCount++;
                    
                }
        }
          
        
            if (bonusSum[0]==bonusSum[1] || bonusSum[0]==bonusSum[2] || bonusSum[0]==bonusSum[3]) 
    {
                bonusAmount1=bonusSum[0];}
                
            if (bonusSum[1]== bonusSum[0] || bonusSum[1]==bonusSum[2] || bonusSum[1]==bonusSum[3]) 
   {
                if (bonusAmount1==0) {
                    bonusAmount1=bonusSum[1];
                }else if (bonusAmount1 == bonusSum[1]) {
            }else if (bonusAmount2==0) {                    bonusAmount2=bonusSum[1];
                }else if (bonusAmount2 == bonusSum[1]) {
                }
            }
                
            if(bonusSum[2]==bonusSum[0] || bonusSum[2]==bonusSum[1] || bonusSum[2]==bonusSum[3]){
                if (bonusAmount1==0) {
                    bonusAmount1=bonusSum[2];
                }else if (bonusAmount1 == bonusSum[2]) {
                }else if (bonusAmount2==0) {
                    bonusAmount2=bonusSum[2];
                }else if (bonusAmount2 == bonusSum[2]) {
                    }
            }
                
            if(bonusSum[3]==bonusSum[0]|| bonusSum[3]==bonusSum[1] || bonusSum[3]==bonusSum[2]) {
                if (bonusAmount1==0) {
                    bonusAmount1=bonusSum[3];
                }else if (bonusAmount1 == bonusSum[3]) {
                }else if (bonusAmount2==0) {
                    bonusAmount2=bonusSum[3];
                }else if (bonusAmount2 == bonusSum[3]) {
                }
            }
            
           if (bonusAmount1<=0 && bonusAmount2<=0) {
               System.out.println("Sorry no Luck this time ");
           }else {
               System.out.println("Congratulations you have won €"+(Math.addExact(bonusAmount1, 
    bonusAmount2))+"!");
           }

        
        
           }
        
        

    }
```

Comment: You need to change the order of your `if .. else if` conditions. Because for every case in `else if` the first `if` is also always true. So if `bonusNumber = 0;` the first condition `bonusNumber < 49` is already true and that `if` is entered and no `else` after that. You need to first check `if(bonusNumber<2)`, and then after that  `else if (bonusNumber<6)`

Comment: Also: In java numbers starting with zero are interpreted as octal numbers. I'm not sure if that is your intention but you probably should just use `6` instead of `06` (same for `2`)

Comment: Hooray! That worked. Just by changing the order. Also good shout on the numbers. I was only supposed to put the "0" into the print! Thanks so much.